# GCP StackDriver: How do I correlate (and nest) info logs with trace logs?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-run

Please help, I've been unsuccessful for 3 days :/

I'm deploying a handful of services to Google Cloud Run, and would like to trace requests and correlate logs to those requests as the requests hop through the services. StackDriver has a great platform for this in "StackDriver Trace". I'm using the Google.Cloud.Diagnostics library in my asp.net core web api's. I am able to successfully trace requests, and start spans, and see the spans nested inside the trace in StackDriver Trace Timeline. However I'm stumped on how to get my logs to correlate with the traces and spans.

The StackDriver docs state that writing "special fields" to the `LogEntry` object will be recognized by the Logging API.

It specifically says this about the `trace` field:

```
The value of this field should be formatted as projects/[PROJECT-ID]/traces/[TRACE-ID], so it can be used by the Logs Viewer and the Trace Viewer to group log entries and display them in line with traces.
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields

I've tried many different things to my structured JSON, but the Stackdriver Trace View doesn't recognize my logs and nest them inside the request trace. Currently I am including both the trace and spanId in the JSON.

Here's one of my logs that StackDriver Trace won't nest in the trace:

```
{
 insertId: "5da6c3a200j0923bx23x2"  
 jsonPayload: {
  ConnectionId: "0HLQI121N94JM"   
  CorrelationId: null   
  RequestId: "0HLQI121N94JM:00000001"   
  RequestPath: "/graphql"   
  message: "Getting Collection of type: FakeItem in GetCollectionOfItemsAsync"   
  messageTemplate: "Getting Collection of type: FakeItem in GetCollectionOfItemsAsync"   
  spanId: "4560986706170855936"   
  timestamp: "2019-10-16T07:15:46.8713740Z"   
  trace: "projects/myProject/traces/04b4a840df0289bb9fddcd62235d3ee4"   
 }
 labels: {
  instanceId: "00bf4bf02d34e072dc1c49x8dj943x4b5609mubm0409u566ad08acf6283d2b5135651fd8f2633e7b06e7dde4b96cfddbf5373a642da0b65fb21cf87a5aad"   
 }
 logName: "projects/myProject/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-10-16T07:15:47.113845061Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   configuration_name: "baseproject-graphql"    
   location: "us-central1"    
   project_id: "myProject"    
   revision_name: "baseproject-graphql-vhglp"    
   service_name: "baseproject-graphql"    
  }
  type: "cloud_run_revision"   
 }
 timestamp: "2019-10-16T07:15:46.871489Z"  
}
```

Here's a log thats generated by gcp that does get recognized:

```
{
 httpRequest: {
  latency: "0.026068056s"   
  protocol: "HTTP/1.1"   
  remoteIp: "73.158.189.48"   
  requestMethod: "POST"   
  requestSize: "1950"   
  requestUrl: "https://baseproject-api.myUrl.com/graphql"   
  responseSize: "2768"   
  serverIp: "152.289.4.125"   
  status: 200   
  userAgent: "PostmanRuntime/7.18.0"   
 }
 insertId: "5da6c3a8j90kjo9db8346"  
 labels: {
  instanceId: "00bf4bf02d34e072dc1cfda1073f2f5ec6888d75e1d75f26259006ad08acf6283d2b5135651fd8f26398n9hu0h9h09gm08g76f67f567fb21cf87a5aad"   
 }
 logName: "projects/myProject/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-10-16T07:15:47.207098181Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   configuration_name: "baseproject-graphql"    
   location: "us-central1"    
   project_id: "myProject"    
   revision_name: "baseproject-graphql-vhglp"    
   service_name: "baseproject-graphql"    
  }
  type: "cloud_run_revision"   
 }
 severity: "INFO"  
 timestamp: "2019-10-16T07:15:46.877387Z"  
 trace: "projects/myProject/traces/04b4a840df0289bb9fddcd62235d3ee4"  
}
```

Any thoughts???